# How to create a panorama image from video frames w/o overlapping frames?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a sliding video files and I want to create a panorama image from this video's frame.

In order to do that I can save each frame from a video file and create such image. But the issue is, I want to bypass the overlapping video frames (the adjacent frames). How can I achieve that? What are the best approach can be applied for such case? Feature matching based algorithm or any state-of-the-art approach?

Any suggestion or pointer would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer as I do not have any experience with extracting movie frames. However, the problem sounds very similar to stitching panorama pictures together from (partially) overlapping photos. There is some software for doing this, e.g. Hugin. On their webpage, they are explaining several difficulties you might have to deal with downstream (lighting, geometry, etc.): http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tech/ . Also, the panorama tools library documentation might be helpful in your project: https://wiki.panotools.org/Main_Page .

Comment: Thank you for these references. I will check it. -)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding overlapping frames, you can check frames similarity based on some features (for example image histogram, maybe in specific image areas as borders and center)

For the panorama creation, you can take a look to the Stitcher class in Opencv

[stitcher API](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d46/group__stitching.html)

[code sample](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d48/samples_2python_2stitching_8py-example.html)

It looks quite simple

```
 stitcher = cv.Stitcher.create(args.mode)
 status, pano = stitcher.stitch(imgs)
```